# Why do std::variant implementations take more than 1 byte for variant of empty types?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-variant

This is mostly trivia question, as I doubt that I will ever need this space saving.

While playing around on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/q6K17fKP6) I noticed that both libstdc++ and libc++ implementations of `std::variant` require more than 1 byte to store variant of empty structs.

libstc++ uses 2 bytes

libc++   uses 8 bytes

I presume it is just not worth the trouble to optimize this, but I wonder if there is any other reason. In particular is there something in standard wording for `std::variant` that prevents this optimization.

Comment: it wont make a difference but you have `-O3` followed by `-O2`

Comment: Variant stores an index, that's at least 1 byte. Variant stores a value, that's also at least 1 byte because you're allowed to take an address of it. How could it be less than 2 bytes?

Comment: @Evg one byte for index, 0 bits for storage.

Comment: @Evg Empty objects can share a storage location with the index.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] inline in your question, not via an external link! Also, what binary layout of that type would you expect?

Comment: imho of someone who doesn't write standard libraries, size 2 is a reasonable expectation for optimization. size 1 could be exceedingly difficult, especially since [`no_unique_address`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) current implementation is hit and miss.

Comment: @bolov I think they can use conditional inheritance. Again I am also not writing std libs :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every object takes up at least 1 byte of space. The counter itself needs to take up at least 1 byte, but you also need space for the potential choices of object. Even if you use a `union`, it still needs to be one byte. And it can't be the same byte as the counter.

Now, you might think that `no_unique_address` could just come to the rescue, permitting the member `union` to overlap with the counter if all of the `union` elements are empty. But consider this code:

```
empty_type e{};
variant<empty_type> ve{in_place_index<0>}; //variant now stores the empty type.
auto *pve = ve.get_if<0>(); //Pointer to an `empty_type`.
memcpy(pve, &e, sizeof(empty_type)); //Copying from one trivial object to another.
```

The standard does not say that the members of a variant are "[potentially-overlapping subojects](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#7)" of `variant` or any of its internal members. Therefore, it is 100% OK for a user to do a `memcpy` from one trivial empty object to the other.

Which will overwrite the counter if it were overlapping with it. Therefore, it cannot be overlapping with it.

Comment: I did not know that `std::variant` is required to be `trivially_copyable` if all of its types are. Very good point.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I should write a proposal for C++23 that disables get(_if) when all members of variant are empty. ;)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: It would be better to write a proposal such that members of a `tuple` and/or `variant` may be potentially overlapping subobjects of their respective containing object.

Comment: @NicolBolas but wouldn't that break code you wrote?, like runtime UB?

Comment: @bolov: While that is true, that wasn't the point. I'm doing a trivial copy to the object inside the variant, not the variant itself.